# Is it possibile to write documentation for custom html components that gets displayed in the vscode popup when hovering the element?

Tags: html, angular, visual-studio-code

Just like it happens for standard HTML elements like [div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hPxf.jpg) I'd like to write documentation for my own custom Angular components that gets displayed when hovering them in some other template ([my rer-card component for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmSDi.jpg))

I tried adding

```
/** 
 * Test!!
 */
```

comments almost everywhere in the component but nothing happens.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

v1.31 has added some functionality to custom html and css, see [custom html and css data support](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_31#_html-and-css-custom-data-support)

> Today, front-end developers often code in a superset of HTML/CSS:
>
> Web
>   Components allow custom HTML elements such as .
>
> PostCSS allows custom CSS properties such
>   as size and not-yet-standardized CSS features such as :any-link.
>   Various frameworks allow even greater flexibility in the source
>   HTML/CSS.
>
> In this iteration, we improved the HTML custom data support
>   introduced in 1.30 and added CSS custom data support. Use
>   `html.experimental.customData` or `css.experimental.customData` to load
>   custom data. (`html.experimental.custom.tags` and
>   `html.experimental.custom.attributes` are removed.) Alternatively,
>   bundle the JSON into an extension with
>   `contributes.html.experimental.customData` or
>   `contributes.css.experimental.customData`.
>
> Finally, if you are writing a
>   Language Server that uses vscode-html-languageservice or
>   vscode-css-languageservice, you can create the Language Service with
>   custom data. Custom data enhances VS Code's understanding of HTML/CSS.
>   For example, with these HTML/CSS JSON contributions, VS Code could
>   provide completion and hover for the custom HTML tag/attribute and CSS
>   property/pseudoClass:

```
{
  "version": 1,
  "tags": [{
      "name": "my-button",
      "description": "My button",
      "attributes": [{
        "name": "type",
        "description": "My button type",
        "values": [
          { "name": "alert" }
        ]
      }]
  }]
}
```

---

```
{
  "version": 1,
  "properties": [{
    "name": "my-size",
    "description": "Compiles down to `width` and `height`. See details at https://github.com/postcss/postcss-size."
  }],
  "pseudoClasses": [{
    "name": ":my-link",
    "description": ":any-link pseudo class. See details at https://preset-env.cssdb.org/features#any-link-pseudo-class."
  }]
}
```

See the link at the top of this answer for more links on how to use this functionality.